# "System.Net.HttpListener" not available in IAppBuilder properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, owin, windows-authentication

I am developing a web app with mix authentication (Owin Token Based and Windows authentication). I have implemented Owin token based authentication and want to implement windows authentication for the users which are marked as active directory users.

In Owin middleware, I want to get requesting user's windows username. I am getting object in OwinContext.Request.User.Identity. However, OwinContext.Request.User.Identity.Name is always blank string.

I found that I should add below lines in startup.cs:

```
var listener = (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
```

However, I am getting key not found exception. "System.Net.HttpListener" is not present in Properties array. I have installed Microsoft.Owin.SelfHost, Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener. However, I am still getting the error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
GB

Comment: I know this is old, but did you ever get a solution to this?  I am running into the same exact problem and can't seem to find any good reference on how to make it available.  Am i missing a reference somewhere in my project?  something need to be added to the GAC on the the server?

Answer (score 0):

For me issue was that project was started as shared lib, not a web app.

Solution was to add a line into **.cspro** file after `<ProjectGuid>` line.

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Then you dont need to add HttpListener explicitly, just reload project and follow this instructions starting from Properties edition part.
[Enabling Windows Authentication in Katana](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/enabling-windows-authentication-in-katana)

You can access principal the same ways:

Get the user in an OWIN middleware:

```
public async Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> env)
{
    OwinContext context = new OwinContext(env);
    WindowsPrincipal user = context.Request.User as WindowsPrincipal;

    //...
}
```

Get the user in a Web API Controller:

```
// In a web api controller function
WindowsPrincipal user = RequestContext.Principal as WindowsPrincipal;
```

UPD: [List of Visual Studio Projects GUIDs](https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs)